# Get effective URL and it's status using cURL

Tags: php, curl, cron

I have written a PHP script which is going to loop through approx. 500 URLs and check their status:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_exec($ch);

$destURL = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

echo $destURL . " - " . $statusCode;
```

Could this be optimized any further OR is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: looks like you have forgotten the `curl_exec( $ch )`! Another way might be to use `curl_multi_exec` but the problem is the response from `curl_multi_info_read` is not very useful. The curl_multi_exec allows the urls to be processed in parallel so should be quicker

Comment: @RamRaider I have added the `curl_exec($ch)` statement in the question. It was meant to be that way, just forgot to put it in here in the question. I was also planning to use `curl_multi_exec` but I cannot figure out how to implement it as I need the final effective URL and their statuses.

Comment: I had alittle play with curl_multi... a little while ago ( been busy sice hence delay ) but as you mention, you can't appear to return effective url or http status very easily and like i said curl_multi_info_read is nigh on useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this quite easily with GuzzleHttp:

```
use GuzzleHttp\TransferStats;

$effectiveURL = '';
$statusCode   = 0;

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$client->get($url, [
    'on_stats' => function (TransferStats $stats) use (&$effectiveURL, &$statusCode) {

        $effectiveURL = (string) $stats->getEffectiveUri();
        if ($stats->hasResponse()) {
            $statusCode = $stats->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
        }

    },
]);

echo $effectiveURL . '<br>';
echo $statusCode;
```